# What is this Java regex code doing?

Tags: java, regex

I just found this method inside a "Utils"-type class in our codebase. It was written a long time ago by a developer who no longer works for us. What in tarnation is it doing? What is it returning?!? Of course, there's no JavaDocs or comments.

```
public static String stripChars(String toChar, String ptn){
    String stripped = "";
    stripped = toChar.replaceAll(ptn, "$1");
    return stripped.trim();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not enough information to say anything useful. `ptn` is a pattern, a regex, and matches on that pattern in the string are being replaced by `$1`

Comment: what do you need to know that is not explained in the java docs of replaceAll & trim?

Comment: Best way to work out what a function is for is to look how it's used.

Comment: Thanks @ilcavero - but this is code that is in *our codebase*, not the Java SE API docs.

Comment: @pnongrata: "java docs of **replaceAll & trim**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to replace everything in "toChar" which matches the regular expression "ptn" with the first group to match in "toChar"

Regular expressions have a concept of groups, for example matching "year 2012" and replacing it with "year 1012", or "year 2006" with "year 1007" (changing the first 20 to 10) can be accomplished by replacing

"year 20([0-9][9-9])"  with "year 20$1"  -- That is, match the entire string, and then replace it "year 20" followed by the first group (`$1`).  The group is the first thing in parenthesis.

Anyway, your method then replaces everything that matches "ptn" in "toChar" with the first group in the regular expression "ptn".  So given
stripChars("year 2012", "year 20([0-9][9-9]");  You would receive back only "12" because the entire text would match and be replaced by only the first group.

It then trips any leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks @Ben (+1) - so if I passed it `String s = RegexUtils.stripChars("year 2012", "year 20([0-9][9-9])");`, then what would `s` be? Thanks again!

Comment: Seems like s would be "12", as it would match the entire string and replace it all with the first group (which is 12)

Comment: Thanks again @Ben, that makes sense (+1)! I'm going to rename/refactor this method. Would you care to bestow to it a new (better, more precise) name? We'd be honored :-)

Comment: Heh, well the most descriptive name is replaceWithFirstGroup though that certainly is boring isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

It's a very short alias, essentially. This:

```
stripChars(a, b)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
a.replaceAll(b, "$1").trim()
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric (+1) - I'm thrown off by the `"$1"` - what does that imply? Can you provide an example of how it would be used? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It's  just `replacing` a string with its own `subset` of matched characters and then trimming the spaces from both end.

**Fo example**

So if you want a word to be replaced by a series of digits of that word

Use the regex `\b.*?(\d*).*?\b`

and then boom,your `replaceAll` method will give these results

```
hey123wow->123
what666->666
how888->888
```

`$0` refers to the whole matched string i.e  `hey123wow`,`what666`,`how888` in this example

`$1` refers to the group.i.e.`(\d*)` in this example i.e.`123`,`666`,`888`

`$2` would refer to the second group which does not exist in this example.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern string that is passed as argument method seems to contain a matching group and the call to replace all is going to replace the entire match to the paatern with the portion that matched the first group. You should look for the call hierarchy of this method to find some regexes passed to the method along with the strings that are being worked upon,

Comment: Thanks @Vikdor (+1) - please see my question under Eric's answer - I have the same question for you!

Comment: You can group portions of your regex to refer to the content that matched this portion using this syntax. Rohit's answer below has links that explain this elaboratively.

Answer (score 0):

```
toChar.replaceAll(ptn, "$1");
```

Its replacing all the occurences of `ptn` in `toChar` with the captured group `$1` which we don't know where it is.

Capture groups are patterns inside `brackets ()`: -

For E.G in the below Regex : -

`"(\\d+)(cd)"`

- `$0` denotes the complete match
- `$1` denotes the first capture group (`\\d+`)
- `$2` denotes the second capture group (`cd`)

  ```
  String str1 = "xyz12cd";

  // This will replace `12cd` with the first capture group `12`
  str1 = str1.replaceAll("(\\d+)(cd)", "$1"); 
  System.out.println(str1);
  ```

For learning more about `Regular Expression`, you can refer to the following links: -

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/